# Feature query to auto-complete mode

Tags: package, ido, auto-complete-mode

Basically, I am looking for an autocomplete-mode that suggests words as ido-mode does on file. Meaning,
if I've typed "em" and the autocomplete suggests two words "Emacs" and "Emacsclient" , it should suggest "Emacsclient" if I type any of "l", "i", "e", "n" or "t" next.

Is such thing already there. Native auto-complete mode doesn't do that. So, is there any other package that any of you are aware of that does such thing?